# Python using PRAW

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I managed to setup a reddit client using PRAW in python, one thing that I can't seem to find a way is to get the current most popular subreddits, I've tried the following:

```
for item in reddit_client.subreddit("all").top():

    #do_something...
```

But that only returns me an iterator with the top submissions, instead of a subreddit object. If possible I would like a list of those subreddits, containing things like the name and the subscribers number.

Comment: As per [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/chztzr/praw_using_python_grab_list_of_subreddits_from/) you can get `item.subreddit` from submission.

Comment: That works, although I still haven't found a way to compute the most popular subreddits